# Big Sur causes segmentation fault for matlpotlib plt.show() command

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I am running a very simple python code to test things...

when it does plt.show() I get a segmentation fault.

It was running fine on the previous os

Any suggestions welcome

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Please provide additional debug information (version numbers for all involved libraries/programs and if possible a stack trace of the crash).

Comment: Which backend are you using?

Comment: I fixed the problem in the meantime. I was using c-shell and switched to zsh. matplotlib now works. I don't know why this happened...